# are django model queries cached?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have a `model_a` that has foreign key to `model_b` and I am accessing `model_b`'s properties like so:

```
model_a = ModelA.objects.get(id=id)

x = model_a.model_b.x
y = model_a.model_b.y
z = model_a.model_b.z
```

Is Django going to the DB and joining the tables to get `x`, `y`, and `z` fields on each line? Or does Django store the result of the first join and then no more joins are needed?

Is this in any way different, performance-wise?

```
model_b = model_a.model_b  # only one join
x = model_b.x
y = model_b.y
z = model_b.z
```

Just curious

Comment: How did you get `model_a` in the first place?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships Might be useful reading if you haven't already seen it.

Comment: also read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets

Comment: "That means the same database query will be executed twice, effectively doubling your database load." thank you, should have started there... so it's option 2 then I guess

Comment: The sentence *that means the same database query will be executed twice* refers to a different example than the one above.

Comment: To be clear, I think both your examples will do 2 separate queries - one fetching model a and then another fetching model b. If you want to only have a single DB query, you want to look at `prefetch_related`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: @TomDalton `prefetch_related` would still do one query for each model. You want `select_related` to get Django to perform the inner join.

Comment: You're right, sorry I was thinking of to-many and not to-one :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [see the SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) that Django with [`connection.queries`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running).

```
from django.db import connection
model_a = ModelA.objects.get(id=1)
x = model_a.model_b.x
y = model_a.model_b.y
z = model_a.model_b.z
print(connection.queries)
```

This should show you two queries, one to fetch `model_a` and another to fetch `model_b`. Django caches `model_a.model_b`, so `y = model_a.model_b.y` `model_a.model_b.z` do not cause further lookups for `model_b`. See the docs on [understanding cached attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/optimization/#understand-cached-attributes) for more info.

You may also find the debug toolbar useful for seeing which SQL queries are running.

The most important tools to reduce sql queries are to [use `select_related` and `prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/optimization/#use-queryset-select-related-and-prefetch-related). For your example, you can use `select_related`. Since you are fetching a single `ModelA` instance, it will reduce the number of queries from two to one, so it probably won't make a noticeable difference to performance.

```
model_a = ModelA.objects.select_related('model_b').get(id=1)
x = model_a.model_b.x
```